# IISExpress not connecting when trying to debug

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm working a ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3) that runs IISExpress to debug the application. However, sometimes (and I haven't figure out what the trigger is) when I debug the application my browser will open to the correct URL but it will just say "Unable to connect".

If I try to refresh the window nothing changes. If I check Visual Studio it still says it's debugging so the debugger or IIS doesn't seem to have crashed. Sometimes if I just click Restart it will work fine. However, sometimes this error continues and I have to kill the IIS process. I've tried deleting the files under `.vs\config` but that didn't help.

Is there any way to fix this or anyway to find some logs to see whats happening? This started in the last few weeks and it starting to drive me crazy.

**Edit**

Happened again and tried connecting via Chrome as well as my usual FireFox. Looking at the developer tools in Chrome I'm seeing the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message.

I decided to check the Windows Event Viewer and found that it looks like IIS Express can't bind to the port.The error message is:

`Unable to bind to the underlying transport for [::]:12345. The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.  The data field contains the error number.`

But why it can't bind to that port I don't understand.

Comment: `my browser will open to the correct URL but it will just say "Unable to connect".` Which browser and share a full screen shot.

Comment: Usually I'm using FireFox but I have tried opening the URL in IE and Chrome to the same effect. It's working again right now but I'll get a screenshot and some logs from the network panel in the developer tools the next time I get the issue